# Horizontal Scroll Table in Bootstrap/CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How could I make it so that a table inside a container with its own width does not follow the width of the container and instead, retain the table's width when it's not inside the container. I have a very wide table that I want to fit inside a col-md-9 container and it displays bad because it squeezes the table to fit to the container. I have tried `min-width` for the table but it is not flexible as adding more columns to my table will squeeze it again. Would it be possible to make the table's width auto while not following the parent's width?

```
<div class="col-md-9" style="overflow-x: auto">
    <table class="table table-bordered" style="width:auto">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          .... contents
        </tr>
    <tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want the width of the table to go outside of the container wouldn't just be easier to make a `col-md-10` or `col-md-11` or `col-md-12` for the extra width instead?  Or are you looking for it to scroll within the container?

Comment: I want it to scroll horizontally as I am placing a sidebar beside it. Also, I am planning to dynamically add columns so I can't set a fix width.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Here is one possiblity for you if you are using Bootstrap 3

live view: http://fiddle.jshell.net/panchroma/vPH8N/10/show/

edit view: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/vPH8N/

I'm using the resposive table code from http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive

ie:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table">
...
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: What about when your massively wide table sits inside a 960px div? I don't get the horizontal scroll bar then! :/

Comment: @Ciwan, re the horizontal scroll bar ... I don't think my suggestion is necessarily the best solution in all circumstances. It's an option which uses built-in Bootstrap styling though, so this is good. Some other solutions I've seen for colapsable tables are http://themergency.com/footable/ , http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-tables and http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-table-roundup/

Comment: It does not work when you have a table with e.g. 30 columns unless I manully narrow the width of my browser window. (Do not ask why the table is so big, the answer would be "the client wants it").

Comment: Yeah, I think I know what you mean @Santhos. To quote from the BS docs http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables , "When viewing on anything larger than 768px wide, you will not see any difference in these tables." If you want to start a JS fiddle, maybe I could play around with it for you

Comment: Thanks, but there is no need. It has quite easy solution (at least for me), I just need to place the table in a div like in the table responsive case a set overflow to scroll.

Comment: paginate button is not at right side, how to resolve can you help

Comment: @SumonBappi I'm not clear on the problem you are describing. If you could reproduce the issue on a pen on codepen.io I'd be happy to look at it

Comment: The table does not appear to do anything special on desktop. The only way to scroll the table is by scrolling the entire window.

Comment: @MaxCandocia, yes with Bootstrap v3 there's no change in table behaviour at viewports > 768px, and they mention this in their documentation as well: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#tables-responsive  . Bootsrap 4 has different behaviour though: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/tables/#always-responsive

Answer (score 31):

@Ciwan. You're right. The table goes to full width (much too wide). Not a good solution. Better to do this:

css:

```
.scrollme {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="scrollme">                        
  <table class="table table-responsive"> ...
  </table>
</div>
```

**Edit**: changing scroll-y to scroll-x

Comment: i think you mean `overflow-x` instead of `overflow-y`

Answer (score 18):

You can also check for bootstrap datatable plugin as well for above issue.

It will have a large column table scrollable feature with lot of other options

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "scrollX": true
    } );
} );
```

for more info with example please check out this [link](http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_x.html)

Comment: Wow! Thank you for linking DataTables. That is an amazing library for me. Wish I would have known about it sooner. Mind = Blown, lol!

Comment: The example fails with styles of the background: https://pasteboard.co/pysDaqPaYgXv.png