# How to force a fixed navbar to have full width of the PAGE rather than the viewport?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my web application, I have a create and edit page for tickets, which include a dynamic input table (in other words, my table populates a row upon clicking a button with a single cell holding a drop down list, and upon selecting the drop down list, it fills the remainder of the row with the necessary input fields). because of this, one row that I have goes beyond the view port. I am trying to find a way to set up my shared layout template to fully extend the width of the header? I have already tried auto and 100% width, but I believe those only apply to the initial view port (I could be wrong). I know it is purely cosmetic, but it looks rather awkward otherwise.

Here is my div tag in my shared layout page:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color:#0139a6;">
```

[screenshot (too low reputation to directly embed image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exXgJ.png)

[After trying to wrap the navbar div in a container-fluid class div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGxr3.png)

Comment: try placing the div inside the div with class `container-fluid`

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. When I scrolled to the right, it still only had the navbar span the width of the initial viewport width, not the ~3,000 pixels that I would like it to cover.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my question is essentially a duplicate of the question linked below. This is because there is no way to style my navbar without hard coding the pixel value, which is obviously not best practice, so instead, applying a scrollbar to my very wide table should do the trick, instead.

[Horizontal scroll table in bootstrap css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19870743/horizontal-scroll-table-in-bootstrap-css)